# Como trabalhar com plugins no CakePHP 3.6 ou 3.6.1

Tags: cakephp, plugin

Como trabalhar com plugins no CakePHP 3.6 ou 3.6.1.

Até a versão 3.5.13 eu trabalhava sem problema, instalava via composer e carregava com 
bin/cake plugin load Nome

Mas na versão 3.6 que foi bastante alterada, eu instalo sem problema com
composer require usuario/nomeplugin

Mas quando vou carregar
bin/cake plugin load NomePlugin

Ele me joga esta mensagem:

> Your Application class does not have a bootstrap() method. Please add one.

Recebi uma dica para adicionar o código abaixo em src/Application.php

```
public function bootstrap()
{   
    parent::bootstrap();
}
```

Assim consigo carregar. Pelo menos não dá mensagem de erro. Diz que carregou. Mas quando tento executar o bake para gerar código ele me diz:

bin/cake bake

```
all groups -t CakeAclBr
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: The plugin class `CakeAclBr\Plugin` cannot be found. Ensure your autoloader is correct. in /backup/www/cake361/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/BaseApplication.php:127
Stack trace:
#0 /backup/www/cake361/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/BaseApplication.php(95): Cake\Http\BaseApplication->makePlugin('CakeAclBr\\Plugi...', Array)
#1 /backup/www/cake361/src/Application.php(34): Cake\Http\BaseApplication->addPlugin('CakeAclBr', Array)
#2 /backup/www/cake361/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/CommandRunner.php(188): App\Application->bootstrap()
#3 /backup/www/cake361/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/CommandRunner.php(134): Cake\Console\CommandRunner->bootstrap()
#4 /backup/www/cake361/bin/cake.php(12): Cake\Console\CommandRunner->run(Array)
#5 {main}
  thrown in /backup/www/cake361/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/BaseApplication.php on line 127
```

Daqui não consegui ir em frente.
Tem alguma dica. Obrigado!

Comment: Você testou colocando um `Plugin::loadAll();` ?

Comment: Não havia feito pois agora na versão 3.6 ele armazena as informações da carga do plugin não mais no bootstrap.php mas no src/Application.php. Por desencargo de consciência eu adicionei o loadAll e depois só o load para meu plugin mas o erro é o mesmo. E ele adicionou meu plugin no Application.php, mas de nada adiantou. Valeu.